# Restore and download non-consumable IAP with Urban Airship

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase

I'm trying to implement a restoration process for my IAPs.
Here's my implementation:

```
    - (IBAction)didPressRestore:(id)sender
    {
        [UAStoreFront restoreAllProducts];
    }
```

While this does restore the purchases, it doesn't re-download the products. I did not write the purchase part of the app, but as far as I understand it, after calling `[UAStoreFront purchase:]` the product is automatically downloaded.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Urban airship is deprecated http://docs.urbanairship.com/reference/iap.html

Try using the Apple IAPs instead.